# DojoToolkit widget.placeAt() method reference

Tags: javascript, dojo

In DojoToolkit documentation, the page "Creating a custom widget" ([this one](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/recipes/custom_widget/)) it's said that in order to instantiate the new widget, you use the following code:

```
var widget = new AuthorWidget(author).placeAt(authorContainer);
```

I spent quite some time trying to find the documentation for "placeAt" method, and can't find it.
Now I know Dijit's widgets are derived from `dijit/_WidgetBase` and `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` classes, but this method isn't in any of these classes.

The nearest thing that searches find is `domConstruct.place()` method.

Anyone knows where the documentation for this method is ?

Comment: it's already a function inside  `dijit/_WidgetBase` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`placeAt(reference,position)` can be found in module`dijit/_WidgetBase` and it provides a shorthand mechanism to put an existing (or newly created) Widget in the dom.

Examples:

```
// create a Button with no srcNodeRef, and place it in the body:
var button = new Button({ label:"click" }).placeAt(win.body());
```

Link to documentation:
http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase

Comment: I tried to understand why I didn't find it in the widgetBase in the first place, as I looked there, then I realized I looked in Reference Guide only and the documentation is in the API part. Maybe links from Reference Guide to API would be helpful to everyone.